# codenameone open t9 instead virtual keyboard

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

How can open T9 or default OS keyboard instead of VKB (virtual keyboard) of codenameone when client focus on `TextField` for input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TextArea` class instead of the `TextField` class which will always use native editing. Unfortunately due to limitations of J2ME it will go to the native edit screen, but if you are OK with that then this is the way you should go.

Comment: thanks a lot Shai for this answer and all of your works around codenameone.